# Bootstrap Steps Disable Next Button and Require One Checkbox for Each Step before Going to the Other One (3 Steps)

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck working on a Simple Long Form using Bootstrap, Javascript and CSS.
My Form is coming along, but I am having an issue on Step 3 - 4- 5 where I disabled Step 3 Next Button unless a Checkbox is happening.
Going to Step 4 I need the same, No Next til at Least One Checkbos is checked. 
Helas ! On Step 4 Next Button won't disable .
   HTML:

....

Here is my JS:

```
    <script>
    //Require at least One Checkbox in each Section 
    $(document).ready(function OneBox() 
        {
            //Step-3
            $("#step-3").on("change", "input", function(e)
              {
                status3=($("#step-3").find("input:checked").length==0)?"disabled":"";
                $('button').prop('disabled', status3);      
                });

            //Step-4

            $("#step-4").on("change", "input", function(e)
              {

                status=($("#step-4").find("input:checked").length==0)?"disabled":"";
                $('button').prop('disabled', status4);      
                });
            $("#step-5").on("change", "input", function(e)
              {

                status=($("#step-5").find("input:checked").length==0)?"disabled":"";
                $('button').prop('disabled', status5);      
                });
        }); 
        // End Require 
     </script>
```

Not Sure where I am going Wrong. !
Thank you All for your Help.

Ed-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using the wrong variable names in step 4 and 5: You saved the checked status of the input to a variable named `status`, but tried to use variables named `status4` and `status5` when enabling the button.

Edit: Another small mistake (and an easy one to make) was that when enabling the button for a step, you enabled all buttons (`find('button')`) instead of just the button for the current step. I have updated the code below to only enable one button.

Try this code:

```js
<script>
//Require at least One Checkbox in each Step
$(document).ready(function OneBox() {
  //Step-3
  $("#step-3").on("change", "input", function(e) {
    var status3 = ($("#step-3").find("input:checked").length == 0) ? "disabled" : "";
    $("#step-3").find('button').prop('disabled', status3);
  });

  //Step-4
  $("#step-4").on("change", "input", function(e) {
    var status4 = ($("#step-4").find("input:checked").length == 0) ? "disabled" : "";
    $("#step-4").find('button').prop('disabled', status4);
  });

  //Step-5
  $("#step-5").on("change", "input", function(e) {
    var status5 = ($("#step-5").find("input:checked").length == 0) ? "disabled" : "";
    $("#step-5").find('button').prop('disabled', status5);
  });
});
// End Require
</script>
```

One final note: With your current code, it is not necessary to select one checkbox in each section on step 3, 4, and 5. The "Next" button will be enabled after checking just one checkbox or radio box.

Comment: Thank you runar, I have tried that it didn't work ... I think the reason could be that when I check a box at Step-3, It applies that to the rest of steps instead of just Step-3...
I can't seem to figure it out.
Thank you .

Comment: Indeed, I already see a few flaws with the code in my answer. Would you be able to post your HTML code as well?

Comment: Thank you! I found another small mistake and I have updated my code above. It seems to work for me now, would you give it another try?

Comment: Grooovey !
Thank you so much, so I guess I was Wrong in using button.. should use Id instead .
It works Perfect now.. I appreciate it Sir.
Many Thanks. Stay Safe !